# PHPExcel dynamic cell generation-iteration

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

Im about the create script that exports data from mysql database and save it to excel file(multisheet). I need to have the cells dinamically genereted. The script does the headings correctly, but the data set is empty. I checked the data is there when i "echo" the $value variable. so it should have work.

Any help would appriciated. Thanks a lot.

```
// Add new sheet
$objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet($i); //Setting index when creating

//Write heading cells
$c=0;
foreach ($res['name'] as $name) {        
  $objWorkSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($c, 1, $name);
  $c++;
}    
//Write data cells            
 $rowcount = 2; // 2-to skip the header
 while($celldata = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)) {
    $col=0;            
 foreach($celldata as $key=>$value){
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col,$rowcount,$value);            
        $col++;
        }            
$rowcount++;
$col=0;
}

// Rename sheet
$objWorkSheet->setTitle("$title");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col,$rowcount,$value);
```

to

```
$objWorkSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col,$rowcount,$value);
```

because the current worksheet may not be the active sheet, so you could be writing to the wrong worksheet